# Flysky I6 transmitter not responsive on betaflightl

Tags: quadcopter, radio-control, input

I am building a fpv quadcopter and I encountered the following problem:

I soldered all points correctly into their allocated pads and ensured there were no shorts. I use a racerstarf4s flight controller and esc combo which is in relatively good condition.

I used a flysky ia6b receiver which is bound to the transmitter as indicated on both devices.

When I start betaflight and continue to the transmitter section when I move the sticks around on the transmitter no input is detected.

How do I make this detectable, how can I make it control the drone?

Thanks

Comment: How do I make this recognised in the betaflight app. How do I make it control the drone

Comment: Will do, can you help me